# How do I correct the error for this program to execute?

Tags: c++

I have tried everything, this is my first C++ program and it not coming out right. I am receiving two error message. `error7:1 warning: character constan too long for its type.` and `7:error: expe`

```
//My first C++ program
#include <iostream>
int main():
{
    "-std::cout << "I will get it" << -std::cout::end1";
    "-std::cout << "I hope so" << -std::end1;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: For next time, please keep the title short and descriptive. The question body should contain all other relevant information, and formatted so that it is readable.

Answer (score 11):

Your code should be fixed like so:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "I will get it" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I hope so" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your quoting is entirely wrong and you have a spurious "`:`" character after `main()`.  You also have some extra `'-'` characters that you don't need.  Finally, in one case you specified `std::end1` where you want `std::endl` and in the other case you specified  `std::cout::end1` (a `'1'` where you want a `'l'`) `std::endl`.  Thanks to Scottie T for that catch.

I believe you want:

```
//My first C++ program
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "I will get it" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I hope so" << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a colon after main(), and the endl should be std::endl, not std::cout::end1 or std::end1 (not the l instead of the 1.)

Comment: I fixed the typos.  Didn't catch all of those.

Comment: @Scottie T:  Huh?  What do you mean?

Comment: @Eddie: you kept a typo "end1" instead of "endl"

Comment: Updated my answer to credit you and to point out the '1' to 'l' typo, which is not obvious!  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding punctuation to the examples.  In programming languages, you must type exactly what you are given.

```
'int main()'
```

is not the same as

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can declare

```
using namespace std;
```

before

```
int main()
```

and you won't need to type that `std::` every time.